# Why is fopen not working?

Tags: c

I can't figure out why this isn't working.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *in, *out;
    //  char *FULLPATH = "C:\\Users\\Jay\\c\\workspace\\I-OFiles\\in.txt\\ ";
    //  char *mode = "r";
    //  in = fopen(FULLPATH, mode);
    //
    //  if (in == NULL) {
    //      perror("Can't open in file for some reason\n");
    //      exit (1);
    //  }

    out = fopen("C:\\Users\\Jay\\c\\workspace\\I-OFiles\\out.txt", "w");

    if (out == NULL) {
        perror("Can't open output file for some reason \n");
        exit(1);
    }

    fprintf(out, "foo U");
    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);
    return 0;
}
```

if I remove the // from the commented lines, the error compiler gives is

> : Invalid argument

I don't understand why (I read all the other threads related, and nothing).
It does actually write the out.txt file OK, so it doesn't seem like a path misspelled problem.

Comment: `in.txt\\ ` --> `in.txt`

Comment: Do you actually have a directory called `in.txt`?

Comment: thanks @SouravGhosh, I didn't know what else to try anymore

Answer (score 3):

Remove backslash after `in.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

The input file name seems bogus:

```
"C:\\Users\\Jay\\c\\workspace\\I-OFiles\\in.txt\\ "
```

The filename is just a single space `" "` and `in.txt` is probably not a directory.

Change the code to:

```
const char *FULLPATH = "C:\\Users\\Jay\\c\\workspace\\I-OFiles\\in.txt";
```

Or preferably:

```
const char *FULLPATH = "C:/Users/Jay/c/workspace/I-OFiles/in.txt";
```

for better portability as forward slashes work in Windows as well as in Unix.

Furthermore, it is easy to provide more information as to why `fopen()` failed to open the files.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *in, *out;

    in = fopen("C:/Users/Jay/c/workspace/I-OFiles/in.txt", "r");
    if (in == NULL) {
        perror("Cannot open input file");
        exit(1);
    }

    out = fopen("C:/Users/Jay/c/workspace/I-OFiles/out.txt", "w");
    if (out == NULL) {
        fclose(in);
        perror("Cannot open output file");
        exit(1);
    }

    fprintf(out, "foo U");
    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the call to `perror()` will include the results from `strerror(errno)` in its' displayed output, without having to have the program include the `errno.h` header file nor the `string.h` header file

Comment: the function: `exit()` is found in the `stdlib.h` header file.  so this will not cleanly compile

Comment: the first call to `fopen()` is missing a trailing double quote `"` in the file name

Comment: when failing the second call to `fopen()`, should include the statement:` `fclsoe(in);` so the code properly cleans up after itself.

Comment: @user3629249: I will add it for clarity, but `exit()` is specified in the C Standard as doing this: *First, all functions registered by the atexit function are called, in the reverse order of their registration [...] Next, all open streams with unwritten buffered data are flushed, all open streams are closed, and all files created by the `tmpfile` function are removed. Finally, control is returned to the host environment.*  Unless you mess up this process via a function registered by `atexit()`, the file will be properly closed.

Comment: @user3629249: regarding `perror` and `strerror`, I agree with you that the code was equivalent to `perror("Cannot open input file");` but I usually try to give more context in the error messages, such as the name of the process and the name of the offending file. It would be nice if `perror` did that and accepted a format string like `fprintf`.  Since it does not, I usually write my own reporting function with these semantics. Some C libraries also support `%m` as a shorthand for `%s` ... `strerror(errno)`.

Comment: It is considered very poor programming practice to leave open files, etc etc around for the `exit()` function to cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

Change backslash to slash.
Maybe you don't have permissions or something like that.

```
out = fopen("C://Users//Jay//c//workspace//I-OFiles//out.txt", "w");

if (!out) 
    perror("fopen");

return 0;
```